# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table?

Tags: sql, database

Creating my database and I can't figure out why `ProductID` is not becoming a foreign key?

```
 create table Products
 (
    ProductID int not null identity(100,1),
    ProductCode nvarchar(25) not null,
    ProductName nvarchar(50) not null,
    Description nvarchar(1000) not null,
    CategoryID int not null,
    StandardCost money not null,
    ListPrice money not null,
    ReorderLevel int not null,
    TargetLevel int not null,
    Discontinued bit not null,
    SupplierID int not null,
    primary key (ProductID, CategoryID, SupplierID),
    foreign key (CategoryID) references Category(CategoryID),
    foreign key (SupplierID) references Suppliers(SupplierID)
 )
 go

 create table PurchaseOrders
 (
    PurchaseOrderID int not null identity(500,1),
    CreationDate date not null,
    StatusID int not null,
    ExpectedDate date not null,
    ApprovedBy int,
    ApprovedDate date,
    EmpID int not null,
    primary key (PurchaseOrderID, EmpID),
    foreign key (EmpID) references Employees(EmpID)
 )
 go

 create table InventoryTransactions
 (
    TransactionID int not null identity(700,1),
    TransactionType int not null,
    CreatedDate datetime2(7) not null,
    ProductID int not null,
    Quantity int not null,
    PurchaseOrderID int not null,
    CustomerOrderID int not null,
    Comments nvarchar(1000) not null,
    primary key (TransactionID, ProductID, PurchaseOrderID),
    foreign key (ProductID) references Products(ProductID),
    foreign key (PurchaseOrderID) references PurchaseOrders(PurchaseOrderID)
 )
 go
```

Here is my error code:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 69
> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Products' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__Inventory__Produ__30F848ED'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 69
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: The `Products` table has a **compound** primary key made up of three columns; any foreign key that references that table **ALSO** must have **all three columns** to reference it. You **CANNOT** reference only part of a primary key - either you reference the **WHOLE** key - or you cannot establish a reference. Since `ProductId` is an `INT IDENTITY` column, in my opinion, that alone should be the primary key - you should add a **unique constraint** on these three columns - not the PK

Comment: hmm okay, ill give it a go! thank you for the reply and help :)